# Workaround for operator overloading in VBA

Tags: .net, vba, oop, math, com

I'm going to need to create a new class in VBA that can support some basic mathematical operations (Add, Multiply etc.). Operator overloading is not allowed in VBA, so for that reason I was thinking of making the following interface

### `INumeric`

```
Public Function Add(ByVal other As INumeric) As INumeric
End Function

Public Function Multiply(ByVal other As INumeric) As INumeric
End Function

Public Function Negative() As INumeric
End Function

'[...] etc
```

Which defines the response to all the operators I'd like to use (`+`,`-`,`^`, `%` etc). Perhaps a separate interface for each would be better, or a duck-typed loose interface (i.e, just define a `.Add` method [like python does](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types), no `Implements`)

This can be used in conjunction with a Mathematics class to carry out the functions in place of the operators:

### `Maths`

```
Option Explicit
'@PredeclaredID

Public Function Add(ByVal first As Variant, ByVal second As Variant) As Variant
    
    If TypeOf first Is INumeric Then
        On Error GoTo defaultAdd
            Dim numericFirst As INumeric
            Set numericFirst = first
            Set Add = numericFirst.Add(second)

    ElseIf TypeOf second Is INumeric Then
        On Error GoTo defaultAdd
            Dim numericSecond As INumeric
            Set numericSecond = second
            Set Add = numericSecond.Add(first)

    Else
defaultAdd:
        On Error GoTo -1
        On Error GoTo errHandle
            Add = first + second
    End If
    Exit Function
    
errHandle:
    err.Description = "Arguments couldn't be added :( try implementing INumeric"
    err.Raise 5
End Function

Public Function Negate(ByVal value As Variant) As Variant
    'Similar sort of stuff
End Function

'[...] etc
```

and then in my code I can

```
Dim result As Variant
Set result = Maths.Add(INumeric1, INumeric2) 'returns INumeric probably
result = Maths.Add(IsNumeric1, IsNumeric2) 'returns IsNumeric probably
```

where `IsNumeric1` just represents some value with the `+` operator defined - e.g a `Long` or `Double` *(or even `String`; "3" + "4" = "34" ofc!)*

---

As you can see, this gets big fast, especially if I want to implement 10+ operators. And for that matter the rest of the VBA `Math` library - my current approach seems verbose and not particularly DRY.

**So I'm wondering** is there any library I can add to my VBA project which defines interfaces similar to these, and uses them in mathematical or logical equations? Or to put it a little differently and avoid an X-Y question; **How can I make custom datatypes which can be used directly in generic mathematical expressions?** I would imagine creating classes which define their own response to operations, but I'm open to other approaches.

---

## Addendum

FWIW, I made an example implementation class (also pre-declared for the Create (Take;) method). It represents a scientific measurement, which has a value and an uncertainty

```
Option Explicit
'@PredeclaredID

Implements INumeric

Public value As Double
Private uncertainty As Double

Public Function Take(ByVal apparentValue As Double, Optional ByVal absErr As Double = 0, Optional ByVal relErr As Double = 0) As Measurement
    With New Measurement
        .value = apparentValue
        If absErr <> 0 Then
            .absoluteErr = absErr
        ElseIf relErr <> 0 Then
            .relativeErr = relErr
        Else
            'must be a perfect number, no errors
            .absoluteErr = 0 'default value so no point
        End If
        Set Take = .Self
    End With
End Function

Public Property Get relativeErr() As Double
    relativeErr = Abs(uncertainty / value)
End Property

Public Property Let relativeErr(ByVal relErr As Double)
    uncertainty = relErr * value
End Property

Public Property Get absoluteErr() As Double
    absoluteErr = Abs(uncertainty)
End Property

Public Property Let absoluteErr(ByVal absErr As Double)
    uncertainty = absErr
End Property

Public Property Get Self() As Measurement
    Set Self = Me
End Property

Public Function toString(Optional ByVal formatWithRelErr As Boolean = True) As String
    If formatWithRelErr Then
        toString = value & "±" & Me.relativeErr * 100 & "%"
    Else
        toString = value & "±" & Me.absoluteErr
    End If
End Function

Private Function INumeric_Add(ByVal other As Variant) As INumeric
    If TypeOf other Is Measurement Then
        Set INumeric_Add = Measurement.Take(Me.value + other.value, absErr:=Me.absoluteErr + other.absoluteErr)
    Else
        Set INumeric_Add = Maths.Add(Me, Measurement.Take(other))
        'or Set INumeric_Add = Measurement.Take(Me.value + other, absErr:=Me.absoluteErr)
    End If
End Function

Private Function INumeric_Multiply(ByVal other As Variant) As INumeric
    If TypeOf other Is Measurement Then
        Set INumeric_Multiply = Measurement.Take(Me.value * other.value, relErr:=Me.relativeErr + other.relativeErr)
    Else
        Set INumeric_Multiply = Maths.Multiply(Me, Measurement.Take(other))
    End If
End Function

Private Function INumeric_Negative() As INumeric
    Set INumeric_Negative = Measurement.Take(-Me.value, absErr:=Me.absoluteErr)
End Function
```

And can be tested with this

```
Sub test()
    Dim a As Measurement, b As Measurement, c As Integer
    Set a = Measurement.Take(10, absErr:=1)
    Set b = Measurement.Take(15, relErr:=0.2)
    c = 3 'treated equiv to Measurement.Take(3, relErr = 0)
    
    Debug.Print "a = "; a.toString; " = "; a.toString(False)
    Debug.Print "b = "; b.toString; " = "; b.toString(False)
    Debug.Print "c ="; c

    Dim aPlusB As Measurement
    Set aPlusB = Maths.Add(a, b)
    Debug.Print "a + b = "; aPlusB.toString
    
    Dim bPlusC As Measurement
    Set bPlusC = Maths.Add(c, b)
    Debug.Print "b + c = "; bPlusC.toString(formatWithRelErr:=False)

    Debug.Print "3.2 + 7.3 ="; Maths.Add(3.2, 7.3)
    
    On Error Resume Next
        Debug.Print Maths.Add("k", 4)
        If err.Number <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Err:"; err.Number; "- "; err.Description
End Sub
```

which outputs this

```
a = 10±10% = 10±1
b = 15±20% = 15±3
c = 3
a + b = 25±16%
b + c = 18±3
3.2 + 7.3 = 10.5 
Err: 5 - Arguments couldn't be added :( try implementing INumeric
```

Comment: Quick thought; `INumeric.Blah` returning `INumeric` means operations can be chained if we `Dim x As INumeric` -  `Set x = x.Blah.Add(1).Negate.Multiply(z)`. However if we return `Variant`, then `Math.Add(x,y).toString` is valid since the default interface of the return value is used, rather than the `INumeric` interface. I wonder which is more useful?

Comment: Interesting question, but [codereview.se] might be a better fit for the question. On Stack Overflow it risks being labeled as off-topic because primarily opinion-based

Comment: @JohnColeman well I'm not sure if I can put it there because it's not fully implemented code yet. Perhaps I should rephrase the question to remove the more reflective sections on approach - I only put them in for context. But what I really want is to know about the possible approaches, not their relative merits - I think that can avoid becoming opinionated. If I do decide to pursue this approach then yep, I agree cr is the place to get feedback, but for now I just want an understanding of the possibilities I'm missing.

Comment: If anyone stumbles across this, please note that my example implementation (measurement class) doesn't use good maths to add errors, so be wary. Also watch the linked posts because I'm gonna put a better version of this on CR soonish

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I am on the same page, but you could do something along these lines in `clsMaths`

```
Private colNumbersForOperation As Collection

Public Enum enmOperations
    enmSum = 1
    enmMult = 2
    enmDivide = 3
End Enum

Private Sub class_initialize()

    Set colNumbersForOperation = New Collection

End Sub

Public Function Load_Number_To_Collection(varEntry As Variant) As Collection

Dim c As Excel.Range

    If TypeOf varEntry Is Excel.Range Then
        For Each c In varEntry.Cells
            colNumbersForOperation.Add c.Value
        Next c
    Else
        colNumbersForOperation.Add varEntry
    End If

End Function

Public Function OperateOnNumbers(enmOperation As enmOperations) As Double

Dim v As Variant

For Each v In colNumbersForOperation
    Select Case enmOperation
        Case enmSum
            OperateOnNumbers = OperateOnNumbers + v
        Case enmMult
            OperateOnNumbers = IIf(OperateOnNumbers = 0, v, OperateOnNumbers * v)
        Case enmDivide
            OperateOnNumbers = IIf(OperateOnNumbers = 0, v, OperateOnNumbers / v)
        Case Else
    End Select
Next v


End Function
```

This can be used like so

```
Dim c As New clsMaths

c.Load_Number_To_Collection 10
c.Load_Number_To_Collection 20
c.Load_Number_To_Collection Range("a1:a10")

Debug.Print c.OperateOnNumbers(enmSum)
Debug.Print c.OperateOnNumbers(enmMult)
Debug.Print c.OperateOnNumbers(enmDivide)
```